# React-native IOS, TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am trying to post a request using FETCH in react-native. However, the request fails sometimes throwing the following message: TypeError: Network request failed. 
The code I use to send a POST request:

```
fetch(query,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(Utils.checkStatus)
      .then(Utils.parseJSON)
      .then(json => this._handleResponseComments(json))
      .catch(error => {

         this.setState({isLoading:false, error: 'Error!'});

      });
```

What is wrong with my code?

EDIT:

found some clues when logging the xhr object:

```
{ UNSENT: 0,
  OPENED: 1,
  HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
  LOADING: 3,
  DONE: 4,
  onreadystatechange: null,
  onload: [Function],
  upload: {},
  readyState: 4,
  responseHeaders: undefined,
  responseText: 'The network connection was lost.',
  status: 0,
```

Comment: It is very hard to guess what could have gone wrong. Try debugging it. Check out the error message in detail and see the stack trace

Comment: The problem is that it happens only when my Iphone is connected to internet through  WIFI. There is no problem when it is on 3G.

Comment: Ok found another clue logging the xhr object: { UNSENT: 0,
  OPENED: 1,
  HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
  LOADING: 3,
  DONE: 4,
  onreadystatechange: null,
  onload: [Function],
  upload: {},
  readyState: 4,
  responseHeaders: undefined,
  responseText: 'The network connection was lost.',
  status: 0,

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I have found the roots of the problem. Increasing the KeepAliveTimeout on my virtual host configuration on Apache solved the problem. Just set KeepAliveTimeout 30 worked for me.

KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 30
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0